# How to test if two collections of objects are in a different order based on one of the objects' properties?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, object, nunit

I'm reasonably new to unit testing and I'm running into a problem. I have two collections (decks) holding objects (cards), with the cards being objects that have an ID, value, suit etc.

I'm writing a unit test to see if my Shuffle() method works, so I want to test if an unshuffled deck (which creates 52 cards with IDs 0-51) and a shuffled deck are in the same order or not.
Obviously, the cards are unique objects, even if they hold the same values. So by definition, testing to see if they're the same will always result in false. I'm very, very new to NUnit (just installed it two days ago) and I'm still struggling with the syntax here and there.

Ideally, I'd want an assertion to check if the order of both collections is the same, with the order being determined by the cards' IDs because, as objects, they are all unique and therefore always in a different order.
Now, I can check if the shuffled deck is no longer ordered by ID, but that would be a bad unit test since it assumes that an unshuffled deck is always ordered by ID. I can also check the unshuffled deck, but it seems rather inelegant to test it that way without actually comparing the two decks.

I also want an assertion to check that my deck constructor creates only unique IDs, but again, all objects in the collection are always unique but I don't know the syntax (if it exists) for checking for uniqueness of one specific property of all the cards.

I've been Googling like crazy, and I've been trying a lot of different syntax things by brute force, but I'm at a loss now. I hope you guys can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: *"Obviously, the cards are unique objects, even if they hold the same values"* You can get around this by overriding the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods on the `Card` class, and then you can just use `SequenceEquals` to compare the two lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine if the cards are in the same order by using the `Id` property, you can simply select that property into an `IEnumerable` and then use the `System.Linq` extension method `SequenceEqual` on them:

```
// Where 'unshuffled' and 'shuffled' are both 'List<Card>' objects
var areEqual = unshuffled.Select(c => c.Id).SequenceEqual(shuffled.Select(c => c.Id));
```

---

Alternatively, you could overried `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on the `Card` class, and then use *that* for the equality comparison. This will help with other card comparisons that may be needed:

```
public class Card : IEquatable<Card>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Card other)
    {
        return Id == other?.Id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Card);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }
}
```

Now our comparison code is slightly more simple:

```
var areEqual = unshuffled.SequenceEqual(shuffled);
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear example and explanation! I was unaware of Select, which was also suggested above, which solved my problem. I'd used lambda expressions in a different part of the code to get the sum of the card values, but couldn't find out how to implement it here. Select solved that problem, so many thanks to you and Guru Stron.

I'm unfamiliar with overriding Equals and GetHashCode and I'm relatively new to programming, so by reading your example I'm not quite sure yet what it does precisely, how it changes the original methods. Would you mind elaborating on that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Equals` is used in many places, including the `SequenceEqual` method, to determine if two objects are the same. The default implementation ([`Object.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netcore-3.1)) uses `ReferenceEquals`, which returns `true` only if two objects are both referring to the exact same thing. By overriding `Equals`, we change that behavior for our class - in the code above we return `true` if the two objects have the same `Id` property.

Comment: `GetHashCode` is a companion method to `Equals`, and one way to think about it is that it can be used to determine if two objects are ***not*** equal - it will always return the same number for two objects that *are* equal, but it's possible that two objects that *aren't* equal may have the same hash code. It should always be overridden if `Equals` is overridden (because it should use the same properties for the hash code as are used for determining equality).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, it's definitely clearer to me now. So instead of comparing the reference, which would cause all objects to be unique, it compares the `Id` now. I assume that I can build more overrides/overloads if I also want to be able to use `Equals` for the other properties, like value and suit? Or possibly with an internal switch?

Comment: `Equals` is only used for comparing the type. You can add other properties into the evaluation, but if you just want to compare the `Suit` or `Value` of different cards, then you would just do that comparison directly - like: `if (cardOne.Suit == cardTwo.Suit)` or `if (cardOne.Value == cardTwo.Value)`.

Comment: Right, of course. Thanks again for the quick reply!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SequnceEqual` with LINQ `Select` like that:

```
class Card
{
    public int CardId { get; set; }
}

Assert.IsTrue(new[] { new Card {CardId = 1}, new Card {CardId = 2}}
        .Select(c => c.CardId)
        .SequenceEqual(new[] {1,2}));
```

Also I would recommend to check out [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) library, sometimes it is not very obvious how to do things there but in general it has some very useful features.

Comment: Thank you so much for bringing Select to my attention, I wasn't aware of that option yet. I wanted to use a lambda expression to get to the card IDs but couldn't find out how to implement that within the assertion syntax. Select solved that problem, so many thanks! I now finally have a smooth, simple unit test without using loops or other heavy logic or long lines of code. Thank you! The unit test now looks like this:

            `var deck = new Deck();
            var idList = deck.Select(crd => crd.Id);
            Assert.That(idList, Is.Unique);`

Comment: @MerelvandenHurk was glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach for your case using NUnit features only is

```
Assert.That(shuffled, Is.Not.EqualTo(unshuffled);
```

Note that this assumes you have overridden Equals for the card object.

Why this works...

1. Your decks all have 52 cards
2. You are also testing (I assume this) that each deck contains the right 52 cards.
3. NUnit Equality over collections is defined as each pair of elements, taken in order, being equal.

For a full set of tests, I'd probably want to make sure that the deck size didn't change and that all elements were unique. Something like...

```
Assert.That(shuffled, Is.EqualTo(DECK_SIZE);
Assert.That(shuffled, Is.Unique);
Assert.That(shuffled, Is.Not.EqualTo(unshuffled));
```